# Psychedelic drug cocktail that cures cancer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'd like to share with friends a short story I read in the early 70s about a man with terminal cancer who cures himself using a drug cocktail of his own making. It allowed him to literally fight his own internal demons. In an O. Henry like ending, he's unable to find his way back from his psycho-pharmacological pseudo-reality, and ends up trapped in his own body. I need to find it before I can share it.

Answer (score 7):

[Carcinoma Angels](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42209) by Norman Spinrad.

You can read it [here](http://will.tip.dhappy.org/blog/Compression%20Trees/.../book/by/Norman%20Spinrad/Carcinoma%20Angels/Norman%20Spinrad%20-%20Carcinoma%20Angels.html).

You remembered it well, including the ending.

> Harrison Wintergreen, who stepped inside his own body to do battle
> with Carcinoma's Angels, and won.
>
> And can't get out.