# Short story involving a man who does battle at the molecular level in his own body

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books, anthology-book

After I saw the movie *2001: A Space Odyssey* in my youth I bought a paperback of the same name. Besides 2001, it had maybe two short stories. I thought all were written by Arthur C. Clarke but that might not have been the case…

One of the included stories was about a man, maybe a rich man, who found a way to go into his own body in order to battle cancer. I remember the title being “Chromosoic Angels” or similar. I can’t remember if the man was fighting the cancer like it was a Hell's Angels motor cycle club or a member of the club battling the cancer. Anyway it was all occurring at the molecular level.

It’s been close to 50 years ago so my memory could be leaving out lots of info…

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Probably [Carcinoma Angels](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42209) by [Norman Spinrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Spinrad), 1967.

> The first story purchased for Harlan Ellison's [Dangerous Visions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangerous_Visions)
> anthology. Nominated for awards. A man who has proven he can do
> anything finds he has terminal cancer and sets out to defeat with
> psychedelic drug cocktails which put his consciousness inside his own
> body to combat the metaphoric Carcinoma Angels.

Comment: That sounds like it! I’ll check it out

Comment: Also the unaccepted answer to this old question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/150462/28516

Comment: Huh. I must have read "Carcinoma Angels" way back when and forgot about it. My first thought on seeing the title of the question was "Blood Music" by Greg Bear, published as a short story in 1983 and later expanded into a novel. It's not old enough.